# Conditional Counter In New Column - R

Tags: r, loops

I'd like help creating a function or loop that adds a value to a new column based on values in the same row of other columns. The goal is to create a kind of scoring system for a survey dataset.

Here's a sample dataframe

```
dfp <- data.frame(id=c("resp1", "resp2", "resp3"), 
                 cat1=c("gov", "biz", "biz"), 
                 cat2=c("dem", "gop", "dem"),
                 liberal=c(0,0,0), 
                 conservative=c(0,0,0))
```

In the above set, I imagine "gov" and "dem" both at 1 point to the liberal column, while "biz" and "gop" add a point each to the conservative column. So, the ideal dataframe would be:

```
dfp <- data.frame(id=c("resp1", "resp2", "resp3"), 
                 cat1=c("gov", "biz", "biz"), 
                 cat2=c("dem", "gop", "dem"),
                 liberal=c(2,0,1), 
                 conservative=c(0,2,1))
```

I tried a for loop, but it didn't work.

```
for (i in length(dfp$liberal)){
  if (dfp[i,][,2] == "gov"){
    dfp[i,]$liberal = dfp[i,]$liberal + 1
  }
  if (dfp[i,][,3]=="gop"){
    dfp[i,]$conservative = dfp[i,]$conservative + 1
  }
}
```

If i get rid of the "i" iterator, the loop correctly adds the number liberal and conservative, but it adds it uniformly to all the rows.

thanks for any help and let me know if i can make this question any clearer. I'm a little new to loops, do if you also happen to have a function that would help me diagnose what i'm doing wrong, feel free to add to your explanation. thanks so much.

Comment: try changing `dfp[i,]$conservative` to `dfp$conservative[i]`.

Comment: i get an error "undefined columns selected". I think that's because changing it to [i][,2] would be selecting one column and then asking r to select the second column as well. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you can see what some of your indexing problems were, here's a working sample of code based on your for loop.

```
dfp <- data.frame(id=c("resp1", "resp2", "resp3"), 
                  cat1=c("gov", "biz", "biz"), 
                  cat2=c("dem", "gop", "dem"),
                  liberal=c(0,0,0), 
                  conservative=c(0,0,0))

          #* Use seq_along and not length (or use 1:length())
for (i in seq_along(dfp$liberal)){
  if (dfp$cat1[i] == "gov"){
    dfp$liberal[i] = dfp$liberal[i] + 1
  }
  if (dfp$cat2[i]=="gop"){
    dfp$conservative[i] = dfp$conservative[i] + 1
  }
}

dfp
```

But the other answers will be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You do not even need the "for" loop. Try

```
dfp <- data.frame(id=c("resp1", "resp2", "resp3"), 
              cat1=c("gov", "biz", "biz"), 
              cat2=c("dem", "gop", "dem"))

dfp$liberal = as.numeric(dfp$cat1=="gov") + as.numeric(dfp$cat2=="dem")

dfp$conservative = as.numeric(dfp$cat1=="biz") + as.numeric(dfp$cat2=="gop")
```

Comment: You can shorten with `'+'(dfp$cat1=="gov", dfp$cat2=="dem")` for each

Comment: Or this method for fun`+(dfp$cat1=="gov") + +(dfp$cat2=="dem")` :)

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune  Those are great comments! I didn't know about such syntax. Where can I read more about this? Or what would be the keywords for search?

Comment: Just hang out around here long enough you'll pick up a lot of tricks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate to create those variables.

```
dfp$liberal <- dfp$cat1 %in% c("gov", "dem") + dfp$cat2 %in% c("gov", "dem")
dfp$conservative <- dfp$cat1 %in% c("gop", "biz") + dfp$cat2 %in% c("gop", "biz")
```

What this line of code is doing?

- `dfp$cat1 %in% c("gov", "dem")` this is 1 if cat1 is equal "gov" or "dem" else 0.
- `dfp$cat2 %in% c("gov", "dem")` this is 1 if cat2 is equal "gov" or "dem" else 0.

Then you sum the two results and you have what you want. The same happens to create the `conservative` variable

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `rowSums`.

```
dfp$liberal <- rowSums(dfp[, 2:3] == c("gov","dem"))
dfp$conservative <- rowSums(dfp[, 2:3] == c("biz","gop"))
```

**Output**:

```
     id cat1 cat2 liberal conservative
1 resp1  gov  dem       2            0
2 resp2  biz  gop       0            0
3 resp3  biz  dem       1            1
```

**Explanation**:

We create two logical vectors to evaluate the conditions:`dfp[, 2:3] == c("gov","dem")`and `dfp[, 2:3] == c("biz","gop")` that are treated as numeric when we apply the function `rowSums`. Probably it is not the quickest option but very concise.

**Data**:

```
dfp <- data.frame(id=c("resp1", "resp2", "resp3"), 
                  cat1=c("gov", "biz", "biz"), 
                  cat2=c("dem", "gop", "dem"),
                  liberal=c(0,0,0), 
                  conservative=c(0,0,0))
```